# Android How To Send Notifications When App Is Closed

Tags: java, android, push-notification

I'm developing small app that sends a notification from an update from a website, but I want it to update the notification when app is closed - similar to when we receive emails.

Comment: Use  service ...

Comment: @TilakMaddy why you need a service when you have FCM?

Comment: Take a look at this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive it explains it quite well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use 
[Firebase Cloud Messaging former Google Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)

This will allow you to send messages from server to ask phone  to display notifications.

Comment: Thanks for this. My question really is how can I send notifications or do anything when app looks closed.

Comment: Basically by adding FCM to your app you will have to create a service that will run in background. When a new message is sent from server to a specific device the Android OS will find your service and will display appropriate notification. Also, when you click the notification it will open your application,

Comment: Thanks @Luci - would you have an example of this (code).

Comment: the whole process could not be covered by a simple example. Please follow the link since there are some prerequisites/steps that need to be done before sending a message from server.

Comment: I have read about Firebase and was not sure what you meant when you said FCM. Don't really want to go down that road, just wanted a few lines of code that would allow my app to be active when closed, similar to email (if possible)